# Input strings from user which are transformed into algebraic expressions that Python uses as variables

Tags: python, variables, math, input, algebra

I am trying to create programs which solve algebraic expressions and/or approximate integrals that are entered in by the User.

I want to be able to have the user enter a string such as x**2, which Python registers as a variable in x. With this, I want to then be able to enter this into a specific location. The code below obviously doesn't work, but it's to represent the idea I have. a and b represent the boundaries of the integral and n is the number of rectangles (arbitrary numbers). Is there a way for the input() to be registered as a variable, such as x**2 when the user enters it in? Thanks.

```
y=0
print("Enter function of integration")
def f(x):
    return (input())
b=10
n=100000
a=1
for i in range(0,n):
    y= (b-a)*f(a+i*(b-a)/n)/n + y
    i +=1
print(y)
```

Comment: Perhaps https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html ?

Comment: _Is there a way for the input() to be registered as a variable, such as x**2 when the user enters it in?_ Yes, and you probably don't want to use it. @SeverinPappadeux shared a link to sympy, if you don't want to use a library for most of the work you'll have to write a parser yourself (it's a fun exercise!).